# How can we convert already recorded(existing) audio file of any format type into flac format with swift language for transcription(Google Speech Api)?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, flac, transcription

**SWIFT**

***For Google Speech Api*** : "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${API_KEY}"

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "languageCode": "fr"
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://speech-language-samples/fr-sample.flac"
  }
}
```

Comment: what did you try so far?